# Setting charset in post request on nodejs

Tags: node.js, character-encoding, request

I want to send post form data to some website using euc-kr charset by request module. And I use iconv-lite module too because nodejs supported charset isn't plenty.

Anyway, The website use `euc-kr` charset, So I have to handle form data's encoding(Node's default charset is utf-8). But it dosen't work well, I tried to change some options so many times but I stucked untill now, So could you tell me some hints.?

```
// added module request, iconv-lite(extendNodeEncoding) already.

function postDocumentForm() {
//Lets configure and request
    request({
        url: 'http://finance.naver.com/item/board_act.nhn', //URL to hit
        headers: { 
            'Content-Type': 'content=text/html; charset=euc-kr'
        },
        method: 'POST',
        encoding: 'euc-kr',
        form: {
            code:'000215',
            mode: 'write',
            temp: '',
            keyCount: '0',
            title: "폼 데이터 중 일부가 한글일 때",
            opinion: '0',
            body:'인코딩이 제대로 되지 않고 있음!'
        }
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            iconv.undoExtendNodeEncodings();
            console.log(response.statusCode, response.body);


        }
    });

}
```

And here is **result**, odd characters.

I tried :

```
euc-kr to binary 
euc-kr to null 
euc-kr to utf-8
delete encoding option 
delete request header
```

[image: result is ????@?@@?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got a soultion, and I solved this problem.

If you send a data as a form using request module, the module change your form encoding to utf-8 by force. So even you setted your form encoding to another charset, the module changes your charset to utf8 again. You can see that at request.js on line 1120-1130.

So, You'd better send a data by 'body' option, not 'form' option.
(as a querystring)

```
body: "someKey=someValue&anotherKey=anotherValue...."
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice how it handles receiving back the body encoding

```
iconv  = require('iconv-lite');

function postDocumentForm() {
//Lets configure and request
    request({
        url: 'http://finance.naver.com/item/board_act.nhn', //URL to hit
        headers: { 
            'Content-Type': 'content=text/html; charset=euc-kr'
        },
        method: 'POST',
        encoding: null,
        form: {
            code:'000215',
            mode: 'write',
            temp: '',
            keyCount: '0',
            title: "폼 데이터 중 일부가 한글일 때",
            opinion: '0',
            body:'인코딩이 제대로 되지 않고 있음!'
        }
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(response.statusCode);
            var utf8String = iconv.decode(new Buffer(body), "ISO-8859-1");
            console.log(utf8String);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi.thanks for your answer but I want to handle request form datas not receiving datas...

Answer (score 0):

After reading the source code several hours, finally I found the simple solution.

First, write your encoding function, which input a string and output a encoded string:

```
const urlencode = require('urlencode');
function encoder(s){
    return urlencode(s, 'gb2312');
}
```

Here is a Chinese encoder based on [urlencode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/urlencode)

Then just add a `qsStringifyOptions` option while posting:

```
request({
    url: 'http://finance.naver.com/item/board_act.nhn', //URL to hit
    headers: { 
        'Content-Type': 'content=text/html; charset=euc-kr'
    },
    method: 'POST',
    encoding: null,
    form: {
        code:'000215',
        mode: 'write',
        temp: '',
        keyCount: '0',
        title: "폼 데이터 중 일부가 한글일 때",
        opinion: '0',
        body:'인코딩이 제대로 되지 않고 있음!'
    },
    qsStringifyOptions: {
        encoder: encoder
    }
});
```